# Animated gifs in photoshop

Tags: animation, photoshop, animated-gif

I have a webpage with a lot of items in it. On the page, I would like to have an animation. Specifically, I am thinking about an animated gif. In Photoshop, I already tried to create a few animated gifs, but they don't animate smoothly like the one in this post.

My animation should be exactly like this one, I just would like to replace the black circles with a custom image: [image: balls line]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be at http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com

But go to "File > Import > Video Frames to Layers"

the file browser popup will show, but only allows video files, change the file type at the bottom of the popup window, to "all files", or just manually type your gif filename (with extension) in the directory your file is located.

in the "Range to Import", select the first "From Beginning to the End" option, and make sure to tick the "Make Frame Animation" checkbox towards the bottom of the options. Then press OK.

and there you go, it will have all the layers of this gif file, so you have to manually edit each frame of the animation to get your desired effect.

Once finished, save as a gif, or the original file. Then you should be set!

EDIT: oh since its for web, go to "File > Save for Web" and make sure you select "GIF".

Comment: this works perfect. +1 reputation for you :)